# gazebo standalone ROS plugin crashes

Tags: gazebo-plugin, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

I am using gazebo 1.7.1 standalone with Ros-Groovy and I want to write a plugin that works with ROS.

Actually, I wanted to recreate the plugin found @ simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_p3d.cpp and I followed the tutorial at [http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros\_enabled\_model\_plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros%5C_enabled%5C_model%5C_plugin) even though it states "This tutorial may not work with Gazebo Quantal and Ros-Groovy"

When my model (with the plugin) is inserted, standalone gazebo crashes with gazebo: symbol lookup error: ../my_gazebo_plugins/lib/libmy_gazebo_ros_p3d.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2tf7resolveERKSsS. (gdb gazebo is not working)

According to the tutorial, I have created rospack.cmake, CMakeLists.txt, and GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH is appended. My manifest.xml includes only  Also I am still using the rosbuild not catkin.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Peshala

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2527/gazebo-standalone-ros-plugin-crashes/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is how I resolved the problem. I am describing the steps for GazeboRosP3D.

- create your package just like a regular ROS package. I am still using rosbuild by the way.
- pull the gazebo_ros_p3d.h and gazebo_ros_p3d.cpp from simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins and change the .cpp file to include the correct header (e.g. #include `<my_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_p3d.h>`
- change your CMakeLists.txt as described by @AndreiHaidu in his answer. Also, add the

  ```
   rosbuild\_add\_library(my\_gazebo\_ros\_p3d src/gazebo\_ros\_p3d.cpp)

   rosbuild\_add\_boost\_directories()

   rosbuild\_link\_boost(my\_gazebo\_ros\_p3d thread)
  ```
- change the manifest by adding

  `<depend package="tf">` `<!-- this is needed for p3d plugin -->`
- in your model.sdf add

  `<plugin filename="libmy_gazebo_ros_p3d.so" name="my_gazebo_ros_p3d">  <bodyName>chassis</bodyName> <topicName>/ground_truth_odom</topicName> <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn> <updateRate>100.0</updateRate> <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise> <frameName>map</frameName> <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset> <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset> </plugin>`
- append the plugin path at /usr/share/gazebo-1.7/setup.sh by modifying

`export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/gazebo-1.7/plugins:<your plugin path>/my_gazebo_plugins/lib`

- source the gazebo setup.sh file

Based on the plugin, you may add different packages in the manifest.

---

Originally posted by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) with karma: 197 on 2013-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-04-25**:
also change DisconnectWorldUpdateStart to DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin in your .cpp file. This is described in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/commits/7070d7a926eb930f0b9cd00534f38f2ecc99ced7